# Replace WCF service library without restarting the service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, windows-services

I have a WCF service hosted in windows service and I there are 2 assemblies the host (.exe) and service library (.dll). When the service library is updated we have to stop the service in order to make it possible to replace the library. I would like to have IIS similar functionality, like  to replace the library without restarting the service. 
Is it possible and how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS uses something called a shadow copy to achieve this.  You could implement something similar for your service host.  Basically, the idea is that before starting the service, you copy the .DLL to some other location and have the host load your service class from that copy.  The host then sets up a file system monitor to listen for changes to the original file.  If it detects one, it stops the service, copies the new file, and restarts.

**EDIT**

(1) To start a ServiceHost using a class in a specific type library, you'd have to use reflection.  Something like the following:

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);

Type serviceType = myAssembly.GetType(className);

ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType);
```

It's not clear from the documentation how LoadFile resolves dependencies.  You may have to hook the Assembly.ModuleResolve event to make this work.

(2) File system monitors surely incur some overhead, but in my experience, it's minimal.  In any case, this is really your only option unless you want to go with an installer for updated DLLs.

(3) I have no idea why your file is locked.  You'll have to troubleshoot that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the anser Peter. Just would like to understand what you mean host restarts, do you mean that anyway windows service must be restarted ?

Comment: No.  The Windows Service application never restarts.  A "restart" means closing the ServiceHost object hosting your service, copying the new DLL, then creating and starting a new ServiceHost object.

Comment: And wouldn't it be a problem to have lot of such services. I mean wouldn't it affect system performance to have lots of filewatchers ? And also how to tell ServiceHost to load assembly from exact directory.

Comment: @Peter this is not working as it is not letting me to copy the library as it is locked.

Comment: Thank you very much peter. I figured out how to implement with having temporary copy of the assembly. Your was really helped me much. I found out the FCL already provides API for shadow copying so trying to check it. Thank you !

Comment: @Peter seems that file is locked because of 

'Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);'

Comment: That makes sense.  Unfortunately, it also makes things a bit more complicated.  You'll have to load the library in a separate app domain.  When you want to update, stop the service, then unload the app domain.  That should unlock the file.  The more I think about it, the more complex this tasks seems.  If the MFC APIs suit your needs, I'd go ahead and use them.

Comment: @Peter no need for MFC. Your answer already explains all, thank you.
I have implemented the "custom" solution with copying and system watcher. Now trying to have the same with shadow copying possibilities already in place for AppDomain.

Answer (score 2):

Peter has one suggestion. Depending on the size and whether you can warrant it, another is to move your infrastructure to at least 2 clustered servers. This allows you to update one at a time, while the other(s) continue to take requests. As long as you version properly (contract changes == new method), this methodology works nicely, as older clients continue to get the same data regardless of your new bits.

Comment: Yes clustered servers can be a practical solution, but I am interested in the replacing lib without service restart whether there is an outage or not.